# Setting typeface to TextView removes my font and sets it to default

Tags: android, string, kotlin, fonts, textview

I make the text bold by setting `typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD`. It works, but my font (Monserrat) becomes default (Roboto). How can I change the boldness without affecting the font?

Function to set typeface:

```
fun setTabTypeface(tab: TabLayout.Tab, typeface: Typeface?) {
    for (i in 0 until tab.view.childCount) {
        val tabViewChild: View = tab.view.getChildAt(i)
        if (tabViewChild is TextView) tabViewChild.typeface = typeface
    }
}
```

How I call it:

```
fun TabLayout.onTabSelectedListener(
    onFollowClickListener: ((String) -> Unit),
) {
    this.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
        override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
            setTabTypeface(tab, Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD)
        }

        override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
            tab?.let { setTabTypeface(tab, Typeface.DEFAULT) }
        }

        override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
        }
    })
}
```

I specify the font only here:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/status_bar_white</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/montserrat</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/montserrat</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, calling `Typeface.NORMAL` or `Typeface.BOLD` creates a preset typeface without any custom font, and only sets the font weight. What you want to do is to create a typeface with the `montserrat` font first, then creating the typeface with that font AND the specified weigh.

Basically like this:

```
val montserratTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "fonts/montserrat.ttf")

// params: typeface family, weight(700 is bold, 400 is normal), boolean italic
val boldMontserratTypeface = Typeface.create(montserratTypeface, 700, false)
```

There is probably a method to create a typeface directly with the fontfamily and weight, but I haven't really checked the typeface class in detail, you can research it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface)

Comment: Works great, thanks. There is one problem that this solution involves API > 28. There is also a way to do it by wrapping the string in html tags and then reading them. Do you know which way is less wasteful?

Comment: the API level restrictions are solved with:
`val typeFace = Typeface.create(fontTypeface, Typeface.BOLD)`
+ if you want to take a font from resources:
`val fontTypeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.montserrat)`